# FastReport - How to create dialog form by SQL text

Tags: fastreport

Report Builder has AutoSearchDialog that creates a Search Dialog with SQL Text.
I want to create auto search dialog in FastReport according to SQL text that is written in AdoQuery in Data section in FastReport.

How can I get SQL text in AdoQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you're looking for. The actually text of the SQL query is available you via the .SQL.text properties of the adoquery object. If you want to populate a dropdown from an adoquery object, then you should use a database lookup control, I think it's called DBLookupComboBox.